# Amazon scraper: Amazor redirecciona a una pagina diferente

Tags: python, selenium, scraping, amazon

Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy haciendo uso de selenium y python para un bot que se encarga de extraer datos de amazon.com. 
Este es el proceso

1. El bot entra a amazon.com
2. Hace una busqueda (El producto que busca lo saca de una hoja de excel que esta en drive)
3. Agarra el primer item que sale con base a su data-asin y/o data index
4. Gracias al data asin puedo entrar a la pagina de dicho producto
5. Recolectar datos
6. Repetir mientras existan productos en la hoja de excel

El problema ocurre en el paso 4, a veces por alguna razon no encuentra el data asin o algo raro pasa y amazon me redirecciona a esta pagina:  https://www.amazon.com/b?node=20547412011&language=es_US y asi por un rato, luego de unos 6 o 7 productos todo regresa a la normalidad

```
try:
        first_result = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-asin]")))
    except:
        try:
            first_result = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-index*='0']")
        except:
            #Proceso que se realiza cuando nada se encuentra
```

Así obtengo el primer resultado, y asi me voy a la pagina del producto:

```
    asin = first_result.get_attribute("data-asin")
    if asin is not None or asin != "":
        url = "https://amazon.com/-/es/dp/" + asin

    # Obtener info del producto

    price = self.get_product_price(url)
    name = self.get_product_name(url)
    availability = self.get_product_availability(url)
    image = self.get_product_img(url)
    category = self.get_product_category(url)
    description = self.get_product_description(url)
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo donde no se cumpla el punto 3?

Comment: Si el bot no encuentra el primer objeto no tendrá un data-asin con el que ir a la URL del producto y simplemente pasa al siguiente ítem